# Waiting operation inside DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a WPF Application that before was using a sync method to get necessary data with the sintax

```
var tagFromDescription = service.GetItem(x => x.Description == tag);
```

Those service's methods have been change and no retro compatibility is present so what I've to do in order to get thing working is something as

```
 public class TestDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
         var tagFromDescription = service.GetItem(x => x.Description == tag).Result;

        return base.SelectTemplate(item,container);
    }
}
```

In a simple WPF project it works but I was wondering if this can lead to deadlock (having different components that works on the main UI thread during the real application lifecycle) or if it's now how can I fix this in order to get things safe?

In other portion of the code (for example in viewmodels) I do

```
var tagFromDescription = await service.GetItem(x => x.Description == tag);
```

And this works, in this case it's ok to do .Result or .Wait() or do I risk a DeadLock?